# How to insert audio files(wav/ogg/mp3) in excel/csv sheet so that I can load it in python using panda?

Tags: python, excel, audio

I need to make an audio data set for ML. When I insert audio files in CSV using "insert object" the files get lost. When I do it in excel I can't load it in colab, it shows nan(null). How do I make the dataset?

Comment: CSV is a plain text, it can't hold binary data. Typically you would have files stored separately and file id / path in your CSV (or other tabular format). Loading audio in `pandas` is a poor idea, it's not geared for audio processing.

Comment: How should I approach then so that I can import audio files from a dataset and use them for implementing ml algos?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.